# Using Config Converter for converting Map values

Tags: converters, quarkus

In quarkus extension, I've a configuration like the following that is mapping properties to a Java map and I'm trying to convert Map values with a custom converter.

`
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "my.prefix")

public interface MyConfig {

```
@WithConverter(FunctionConverter.class)
Map<String, Function> functions();
```

}
`

This fails at build time with error:

> java: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ArrayType cannot be cast to class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType (com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ArrayType is in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app'; javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType is in module java.compiler of loader 'platform')

Is there a way I can achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following definition instead:

```
Map<String,  @WithConverter(FunctionConverter.class) Function> functions();
```

Comment: My apologies for te late reply on your suggestion @Roberto Cortez and thankyou for your answer. Unfortunately I'm getting the same compilation error also with what you suggested. I've also tried directly annotating the field with a converter handling the whole map with same result. I guess this deserves an issue on the quarkus repo....

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I was able to workaround this by replacing Function as a type for the Map values, that is an interface in my code base, with an implementing class. eg. `Map<String,  @WithConverter(FunctionConverter.class) Function> functions();` I'm marking as accepted the answer from @Roberto Cortez as it was fixing the usage I was doing of the @WithConverter annotation.